# posts_where Fails with More than One Custom Field in Query

Tags: sql, posts-where

Querying either of the 2 fields individually gives the expected result (posts are displayed).

But, when both fields are included in the query (ex = 'foo' and 'bar' shown in below example), then no posts are displayed.

```
function do_stuff( ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return "
    AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'foo' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '1') 
    AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'bar' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '1')";
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'do_stuff' );
```

Here is a print_r of the WP_Query:

```
[query] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => testPostType
        [pagination] => 1
        [posts_per_page] => 10
        [paged] => 1
    )

[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id  WHERE 1=1 
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'foo'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '1')
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'bar'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '1')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
[posts] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

Have I made a logic error in the sql? How can I get the posts to display as expected?

Comment: Can you add the SQL generated after your filter has been added?

Comment: Thanks Chris_O, I added the results of doing a print_r to the question. Please let me know if there is more I can provide.

Comment: If you use OR in the where condition instead of AND for meta fields then is the result getting displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about your query. You are asking that `$wpdb->postmeta.meta_key` be ***both*** "foo" and "bar". That will never happen. If you ran this in a context where you'd get to read MySQL debugging data (PhpMyAdmin's `SQL` console will do this) you would probably see a warning about an "impossible where clause". You need to `JOIN` on the post meta table for one of the values, but as near as I can tell `WP_Query` will do this too.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'foo',
      'value' => '1',
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'bar',
      'value' => '1',
    )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you look at the SQL for that query-- `var_dump($qry->request);`-- you will see the `JOIN` I am talking about.

You can do the same with a filter on `pre_get_posts`.

```
function set_post_meta_wpse_111456($qry) {
  $qry->set(
    'meta_query',
    array(
      array(
        'key' => 'foo',
        'value' => '1',
     ),
     array(
       'key' => 'bar',
       'value' => '1',
     )
  );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','set_post_meta_wpse_111456');
```

***WARNING***: As written above, that will effect every query on the site so you do need to add conditions to limit where that runs.

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum, I thought something was off with my query. Could your solution also work with more complex queries, such as: Find all posts where foo equals 1 OR 2, AND bar equals 3 OR  4 AND baz is any value between 10 to 20?

Comment: Yes, `WP_Query` will support more complicated queries. [Take a look at the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). If I understand you, it will support the conditions you want though it does not support all of the very complicated queries that people sometimes request.